# grepping lines from a document using xargs

Tags: unix, grep, xargs

Let's say I have queries.txt.

queries.txt:

```
cat
dog
123
```

now I want to use them are queries to find lines in myDocument.txt using grep.

```
cat queries.txt | xargs grep -f myDocument.txt
```

myDocument has lines like

```
cat
i have a dog
123
mouse
```

it should return the first 3 lines. but it's not. instead, grep tries to find them as file names. what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here, you just need:

```
grep -f queries.txt myDocument.txt
```

This causes `grep` to read the regular expressions from the file `queries.txt` and then apply them to `myDocument.txt`.

In the `xargs` version, you were effectively writing:

```
grep -f myDocument.txt cat dog 123
```

If you absolutely must use `xargs`, then you'll need to write:

```
xargs -I % grep -e % myDocument.txt < queries.txt
```

This avoids a UUOC — Useless Use of `cat` – award by redirecting standard input from `queries.txt`.  It uses the `-I %` option to specify where the replacement text should go in the command line.  Using the `-e` option means that if the pattern is, say `--help`, you won't run into problems with (GNU) `grep` treating that as an argument (and therefore printing its help message).

Answer (score 1):

The [grep](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=grep) `-e` option will take a pattern string as an argument. `-f` treats the argument as a file name of a file with patterns in it.